# Error in startup of apache server v3.2.1 in windows 7

Tags: php, apache

I am getting this error on my XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1.
I downloaded the 5.6.12 / PHP 5.6.12 version and installed it. My mysql panel is running successfully but Apache is not running. And when i try to start Apache server, this error is coming.

```
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3232!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3232!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port



7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3232!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3232!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
7:25:04 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
7:25:04 AM  [mysql]     Autostart aborted: MySQL is already running
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
7:25:05 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

any help regarding this..?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should probably ask that question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like another program is using port 80. Maybe skype (I've had this issue before with skype). Try to find out which program is using ports 80 and 443, and close them. You can use command

```
netstat -a
```

to check if the port is being used. Why do you mentioned Tomcat? Are you using Java or PHP???

Another possibility is that a program crashed (Eclipse for instance) and made the server hang with the port unavailable. In those cases I had to restart my computer.